# I am unable to correctly return the url of an uploaded asset

Tags: templating, assets, url, field, image

I'm a newcomer to Craft from the far-off lands of WordPress. I hope my stay is long and fruitful, but at the moment that prospect is in danger. The problem I'm having must be embarrassingly simple, but I can't find my way through it.

The simple task I am attempting to accomplish it to display an image I uploaded to an entry via a new asset field.

If there is a method or practice for displaying an image via asset fields found on the internet, I have tried it. Currently, this is how I am trying to render the image in my twig file:

```
{% for image in entry.featuredImage %}
    <img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="blah">
{% endfor %}
```

No image shows up.

When I `dump(image)`, should it be returning an array with 666 lines? I understand an asset returns a kind of Asset File Model (although I don't entirely understand *what* that means), but I find it hard to believe it's supposed to be that large.

Hoping to find at least the url of the asset, I perform `dump(image.url)`, but it only returns `bool(false)`. Why would it be doing that?

I created my `uploads` directory, and setup my asset source. I've tried doing this on an entirely fresh, up-to-date and clean install, but it still behaves the same way.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer in a similar post here: [Image asset url is not being output](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16578/image-asset-url-is-not-being-output)

My problem was with my Asset Source settings. Now that I think about it, it's obvious: I had no public URL declared for assets from my 'Uploads' source. Giving that a public url fixed the problem.

As I said, it's obvious now, but it'd be nice in the documentation could make even just a small reference to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% set image = entry.featuredImage.first() %}
{% if image %}
    <img src="{{ image.url }}"/>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried this already, and it behaves the same. When I search the object returned by `dump(image)` there is no `url` key to be found. I can successfully return `{{ image.filename }}`, but no url!

Comment: For your answer to be as helpful as possible for the OP and others, it's always best to explain any code solutions and describe why the original code didn't work.