# Image URL problem

Tags: assets

I experiencing some kind of missconfiguration with images - there is no way to get /print URL in output html (on backend is fine):

[image]

We´ve tried many ways, but no way:

```
{% for image in entry.imagenDestacadaNoticia %}

    <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}"  alt="{{ image.title }}">

{% endfor %}
```

Where could be the problem to look into?

Comment: your issue is Craft 3 related?

Comment: your field name is correct? Based on the camelcasing I would think the field name needs to be imageDestacodaNoticia (without the n)

Comment: Does this thread answer your question? http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/16578/45

Comment: Are you certain you are using Craft 3? I suspect that you are not, since the public beta hasn't even shipped yet.

Comment: I'm using Craft CMS 2.6.2958 free edition (this is my firs Craft site). The URL above do not solve my issue... thanks. Before I installed other version on demo and it was working well. Looking thrue configuration on demo and "real" I cant find where is the issue or missconfiguration.... I've tried to output url many way, but do not get it. I just get blank < img src...> Im desesperate at this point...

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the problem: misscounfiguration of assets (activate public URL). Close the question.